# Odd Scale Change When Updating Chart Type

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a population pyramid chart with each gender as series. The user needs the ability to change the series chart types. The default is bar and they want to be able to change to line. I have created a function that will change the chart type. This works but, the series that is "going to the left" (or negative value) has a really odd value/scale change. If I hide the right series then the left series value/scale is corrected. Show the right series and the graph looks off again. If I change back to bar type series then the series looks correct.

My code to change the chart series type:

```
  var mainGraphFormatType = $('#ddlGraphFormatDropDown');

  mainGraphFormatType.change(function() {
    var chartM = $('#container').highcharts();
    if ($(this).val() != 'null') {
      var selType = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      if (selType == 'scatter') {
        selType = 'line';
      }
      changeType(chartM, selType);
    }
  });

  function changeType(chart, newType) {
    newType = newType.toLowerCase();
    var serie = chart.series;
    for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
      var item = serie[i];
      item.update({
        type: newType
      });
      var isLegendOn = chart.legend.options.enabled;
      if (isLegendOn) {
        if (!item.showInLegend) {
          item.update({
            showInLegend: true
          });
          item.options.showInLegend = true;
          chart.legend.renderItem(item);
          chart.legend.render();
        }
      }
    }
    changeChartTypeSingSeries(chart);
  }

  function changeChartTypeSingSeries(chart) {
    var serie = chart.series;
    for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
      var item = serie[i];
      if (!item.visible) {
        item.hide();
      }
    }
  }
```

I have replicated this issue from the highcharts demo pyramid chart [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/vLpc807z/).

Comment: Seems to be happening because of `stacking: 'normal'`, if you comment that out the line looks normal.

Comment: @ewolden, well, I could remove that but that will add a lot of complexity to the code. The graph type selection is a general control/method used on all our charts. This is the first time we are adding in a population pyramid that requires the negate+positive values stacked. Will check to see if I can get the stacking options and change if necessary. But, that is going to mess with the alignment of the series.

Comment: I didnt mean to suggest you should remove it. I was merely pointing out what I think is causing it to behave that way, so that more people can try to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround with swapping stacking property on `render` event:

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  events: {
    render: function() {
      var chart = this,
        series = chart.series[0],
        options = chart.options,
        stacking = options.plotOptions.series.stacking;

      if (stacking === 'normal' && series.type === 'line') {
        chart.update({
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              stacking: ''
            }
          }
        });
      } else if (stacking === '' && series.type === 'bar') {
        chart.update({
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              stacking: 'normal'
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hdL7eb9x/

Comment: A variant of this i can use I think. Need to check what kind of chart I am creating and add the `chart.events.render` function as needed.